# How to Display the response of the servlet paricullar portion of the web page?

Tags: java, html, css, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have HTML page and servlet file.Now i want to get the request from the html file and process it into my servlet file and finally i want to display my servlet response only particular portion of my default html page having CSS.

how i so my servlet response only particular portion of my default html page having CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is your friend. Read this article: J2EE and AJAX: [AJAX with Servlets](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/J2EE-and-AJAX-AJAX-with-Servlets/)